# Reading Data from a File into Separate Int Values

Tags: c++, file

I am looking to take in data values from a file and store them in separate integer variables. I have the following variables:

```
int r;
int c;
int startR;
int startC;
```

The file provides the values in the form:

```
2 32 12 4
```

These are just examples and I need to store these four values in the variables. I am using the getline function to get the line and then calling a split function to take the string and split it and put it into the four values.

```
getline(fileName, line);
split(line);

void split(string l)
{
  //this is where I am struggling to find the best way to get the values stored in the ints
}
```

Comment: You can use `std::istream` with the line, and simple text formatted extraction with `>>`.

Comment: So would I not need the split function? I would just use isstream(line) and then line >> r, c, startR, startC?

Comment: More like `std::istringstream iss(line);` and `iss >> r >> c >> startR >> startC;`, but yes.

Answer (score 1):

Read straight from the file into your variables.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::ifstream file("test.txt");
    int a, b, c, d;
    if (file.is_open()) {
        cout << "Failed to open file" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if (file >> a >> b >> c >> d) { // Read succesfull
        cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << d << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are still having problems parsing the information from the file, you can take a very simple approach -- continuing with your `getline` beginning to then create a `stringstream` object from `line` that will allow you to use the operator making sequential calls to get each next value from your line. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main (void) {

    int r, c, startR, startC;           /* variable declarations */
    std::string fname, str;

    std::cout << "Enter a filename: ";  /* prompt for filename */
    std::cin >> fname;

    std::ifstream f (fname);            /* open file */
    if (!f.is_open()) {                 /* validate open for reading */
        std::cerr << "error: file open failed\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::getline (f, str);              /* read line into str */

    std::stringstream s (str);          /* create stringstream s with str */
    s >> r >> c >> startR >> startC;    /* parse data */

    /* output parsed data for confirmation */
    std::cout << "r: " << r << "  c: " << c << "  startR: " << startR 
            << "  startC: " << startC << "\n";

    f.close();                          /* close file */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/4nums.txt
2 32 12 4
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strstreamtst
Enter a filename: dat/4nums.txt
r: 2  c: 32  startR: 12  startC: 4
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
FILE* in = NULL;
int r;
int c;
int startR;
int startC;

errno_t fin = freopen_s(&in, "input.txt", "r", stdin);
assert(0x0 == fin);
cin >> r >> c >> startR >> startC;
```

Here with freopen(), "cin" will read data values from file rather than from standard input.

Comment: The `_s` functions part of proposed Extension 1 to the C-library are only available on windoze and their behavior on return is different from the normal `freopen` functions that are in the C library. Best to determine whether they are even available to the questioner before providing them as an answer. Just don't have enough info to tell here one way or the other.

Comment: Thanks David. I will keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: What's with the `FILE *` and the `freopen()` on `stdin`? You *can* open a file in proper C++, without resorting to such C hackery...

Comment: Also, why are you checking against `0x0` instead of `NULL`, and with a Yoda conditional ("if zero the value is")? Why showcasing `assert()` for a runtime sanity check (which would then not be done for release code)? Sorry, but that's not really C++, hence my downvote.

Answer (score -2):

Your just need to store the value into the appropriate variable.

See [this for more information.](https://www.uow.edu.au/~lukes/TEXTBOOK/notes-cpp/io/readtextfile.html)

Comment: It is good practice to elaborate on the contents of the link in your answer.